# What is the origin of the term "moments" in the study of random variables?

Tags: statistics, math-history, moment-generating-functions

I understand what the moments are, I just want to know who picked the term "moment" and why? How is the word "moment" related to different but related ways to describe the shape of a random variable?

Comment: Probably from *moment of inertia*.

Comment: "In physics, a moment is a turning effect of a force. It is an expression involving the product of a distance and a physical quantity, and in this way it accounts for how the physical quantity is located or arranged."

So, perhaps it's related to this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll find anything much better than this: [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html) says

> **Moment** was taken into Statistics from Mechanics by Karl Pearson when he treated the frequency-curve (or observation curve) as the sheet enclosed by the curve and the horizontal axis. See his "Asymmetrical Frequency Curves," *Nature* October 26th 1893: "Now the centre of gravity of the observation curve is found at once, also its area and its first four moments by easy calculation." (OED2).